# Remove custom spacing in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uistackview

I have a stackview with three subviews:

```
stackView.spacing = 8.0

stackView.addArrangeSubview(view1)
stackView.addArrangeSubview(view2)
stackView.addArrangeSubview(view3)
```

At some point, I add custom spacing after view2:

```
stackView.setCustomSpacing(24.0, after: view2)
```

Now, I want to remove the custom spacing. Is this possible using UIStackView? The only way I can think of is

```
stackView.setCustomSpacing(8.0, after: view2)
```

but this will break if I ever change the spacing of my stackView to something other than 8.0, because spacing will remain 8.0 after view2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this extension:

```
extension UIStackView {

    // remove all custom spacing
    func removeCustomSpacing() -> Void {
        let a = arrangedSubviews
        arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        a.forEach {
            addArrangedSubview($0)
        }
    }

    // remove custom spacing after only a single view
    func removeCustomSpacing(after arrangedSubview: UIView) -> Void {
        guard let idx = arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: arrangedSubview) else { return }
        removeArrangedSubview(arrangedSubview)
        insertArrangedSubview(arrangedSubview, at: idx)
    }
}
```

Use it simply as:

```
myStackView.removeCustomSpacing()
```

or, if you are setting custom spacing on multiple views, and you want to remove it from only one view, use:

```
theStackView.removeCustomSpacing(after: view2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should re-create `stackView` with specific spacing and replace the old one with the new `stackView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let spacingView = UIView()

[View1, View2, spacingView, View3].forEach { view in 
  stackView.addArrangeSubview(view)
}
```

when you want to remove it just remove the `spacingView` from the array and you can play with width and height of the `spacingView` like you prefer